# Value not coming first time after doing login

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

I am opening one fragment after doing login into my application. I am not able to see value coming for the first time(When loading). But When i am changing date then the values are coming.

***Here is my code!!***

```
 package com.bharatwellness.mainactivities;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import com.bharatwellness.libraries.DatabaseHandler;
import com.project.homepagedemo.R;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CalorieHomeFragmentActivity extends Fragment{

    private double calorie;
    private String fat;
    private String carbohydrate;
    private String protein;
    private TextView tvcalorieoutput;
    private TextView tvfatout;
    private TextView tvcarbsout;
    private TextView tvproteinout;
    private TextView tvcalorieburnedout;
    public String name;
    public double weight;
    private TextView calorieconsumedout;
    private double dbcalorie;
    private double dbcalorieburned;
    private String formattedDate;
    private TextView currentDate;
    private ImageView prevMonth;
    private ImageView nextMonth;
    private TextView dailyfat;
    private TextView dailycarbs;
    private TextView dailyprotein;
    private String checkingdate;
    private double totalfat = 0;
    private double totalcarbs = 0;
    private double totalproteins;
    Calendar c;
    Calendar d;
    SimpleDateFormat df;
    Date date1;
    Date date2;
    private ImageButton mealbutton;
    private ImageButton exercisebutton;
    private ImageButton drinksbutton;
    private TextView tvcalorieremainingout;
    private double totalremaining;
    private ImageButton tipsbutton;
    private SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
    public static final String Name = "nameKey";


    public CalorieHomeFragmentActivity(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calorie_home, container, false);

        Bundle bundle = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundle != null) {

            formattedDate = bundle.getString("formattedDate");
            name = bundle.getString("name");
            System.out.println("calorie home fragment"+name);
            System.out.println("calorie home fragment"+formattedDate);
        }

        sharedpreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        calorieconsumedout =(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.calorieconsumedout);
        tvcalorieoutput =(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.calorieoutput);
        tvfatout = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragmentfatout);
        tvcarbsout = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragmentcarbsout);
        tvproteinout = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragmentproteinout);
        tvcalorieburnedout = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.calorieburnedout);
        tvcalorieremainingout = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.calorieremainingout);
        dailyfat = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.Dailyfat);
        dailycarbs = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.Dailycarbs);
        dailyprotein = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.Dailyprotein);
        currentDate = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.currentMonth);
        prevMonth = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.prevMonth);
        nextMonth = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.nextMonth);
        mealbutton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mealsbutton);
        exercisebutton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.exerciseButton);
        drinksbutton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.drinksbutton);
        tipsbutton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mytipsbutton);



        Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(Name, name);
        editor.commit();


        if(formattedDate == null){
            c = Calendar.getInstance();
            System.out.println("Current time => " + c.getTime());
            df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",java.util.Locale.getDefault());
            formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
            System.out.println("calorie home fragment inside if first time "+ formattedDate);
            try {
                date1 = df.parse(formattedDate);
                c.setTime(date1);
            } catch (ParseException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("date in fragment" + formattedDate);
            c = Calendar.getInstance();
            df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",java.util.Locale.getDefault());
            System.out.println("inside else");
            try {
                date1 = df.parse(formattedDate);
                c.setTime(date1);
            } catch (ParseException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        //calendar for checking date
        d = Calendar.getInstance();

        checkingdate = df.format(d.getTime());
        try {
            date2 = df.parse(checkingdate);
            d.setTime(date2);
        } catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(date1.equals(date2))
        {
            nextMonth.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else if(date1.after(date2)){

            final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "You Cannot Make Future Entries!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();

            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    toast.cancel(); 
                }
            }, 3000);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),CalorieMainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("formattedDate", checkingdate);
            intent.putExtra("name", name);
            startActivity(intent);     

        }
        else
        {
            nextMonth.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        selectdata();

        DecimalFormat dd = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
        totalremaining =  Double.parseDouble(dd.format(totalremaining));    
        totalremaining = calorie - (dbcalorie - dbcalorieburned);
        calorie = Double.parseDouble(dd.format(calorie));
        totalfat = Double.parseDouble(dd.format(totalfat));
        totalcarbs = Double.parseDouble(dd.format(totalcarbs));
        totalproteins = Double.parseDouble(dd.format(totalproteins));       
        dbcalorie = Double.parseDouble(dd.format(dbcalorie));
        dbcalorieburned = Double.parseDouble(dd.format(dbcalorieburned));
        totalremaining = Double.parseDouble(dd.format(totalremaining));

        tvcalorieoutput.setText("" + calorie);
        System.out.println("the value of fat" + fat);
        tvfatout.setText(fat);
        tvcarbsout.setText("" + carbohydrate);
        tvproteinout.setText("" + protein);
        calorieconsumedout.setText("" + dbcalorie);
        tvcalorieburnedout.setText("" + dbcalorieburned);
        System.out.println("this is the calorie burned out "+dbcalorieburned);
        tvcalorieremainingout.setText("" + totalremaining);
        currentDate.setText(formattedDate);
        dailyfat.setText("" + totalfat);
        dailycarbs.setText("" + totalcarbs);
        dailyprotein.setText("" + totalproteins);

        prevMonth.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                c.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
                formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
                currentDate.setText(formattedDate);
                d = Calendar.getInstance();
                checkingdate = df.format(d.getTime());
                if(formattedDate.equals(checkingdate))
                {
                    nextMonth.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else
                {
                    nextMonth.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                selectdata();

                DecimalFormat dd = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
                totalremaining =  Double.parseDouble(dd.format(totalremaining));

                totalremaining = calorie - (dbcalorie - dbcalorieburned);
                calorie = Double.parseDouble(dd.format(calorie));
                totalfat = Double.parseDouble(dd.format(totalfat));
                totalcarbs = Double.parseDouble(dd.format(totalcarbs));
                totalproteins = Double.parseDouble(dd.format(totalproteins));
                dbcalorie = Double.parseDouble(dd.format(dbcalorie));
                dbcalorieburned = Double.parseDouble(dd.format(dbcalorieburned));
                totalremaining = Double.parseDouble(dd.format(totalremaining));

                tvcalorieoutput.setText("" + calorie);
                tvfatout.setText("" + fat);
                tvcarbsout.setText("" + carbohydrate);
                tvproteinout.setText("" + protein);
                calorieconsumedout.setText("" + dbcalorie);
                tvcalorieburnedout.setText("" + dbcalorieburned);
                tvcalorieremainingout.setText("" + totalremaining);
                currentDate.setText(formattedDate);
                dailyfat.setText("" + totalfat);
                dailycarbs.setText("" + totalcarbs);
                dailyprotein.setText("" + totalproteins);

            }
        });
        nextMonth.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v){
                c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
                currentDate.setText(formattedDate);
                final Calendar d = Calendar.getInstance();
                checkingdate = df.format(d.getTime());

                if(formattedDate.equals(checkingdate))
                {
                    nextMonth.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else
                {
                    nextMonth.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                selectdata();
                DecimalFormat dd = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

                totalremaining =  Double.parseDouble(dd.format(totalremaining));            
                totalremaining = calorie - (dbcalorie - dbcalorieburned);
                calorie = Double.parseDouble(dd.format(calorie));
                totalfat = Double.parseDouble(dd.format(totalfat));
                totalcarbs = Double.parseDouble(dd.format(totalcarbs));
                totalproteins = Double.parseDouble(dd.format(totalproteins));

                dbcalorie = Double.parseDouble(dd.format(dbcalorie));
                dbcalorieburned = Double.parseDouble(dd.format(dbcalorieburned));
                totalremaining = Double.parseDouble(dd.format(totalremaining));

                tvcalorieoutput.setText("" + calorie);
                tvfatout.setText("" + fat);
                tvcarbsout.setText("" + carbohydrate);
                tvproteinout.setText("" + protein);
                calorieconsumedout.setText("" + dbcalorie);
                tvcalorieburnedout.setText("" + dbcalorieburned);
                tvcalorieremainingout.setText("" + totalremaining);
                currentDate.setText(formattedDate);
                dailyfat.setText("" + totalfat);
                dailycarbs.setText("" + totalcarbs);
                dailyprotein.setText("" + totalproteins);
            }
        });
        mealbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v){

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),CalorieAMealsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", name);
                intent.putExtra("formattedDate", formattedDate);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
        exercisebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v){

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),ExerciseCDiaryActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", name);
                intent.putExtra("weight", weight);
                intent.putExtra("created_at", formattedDate);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        drinksbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v){

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),CalorieBFoodItemActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", name);
                intent.putExtra("foodtype", "Drinks");
                intent.putExtra("formattedDate", formattedDate);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
        tipsbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v){

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),TipsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", name);
                intent.putExtra("formattedDate", formattedDate);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });

        final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                    int dayOfMonth) {

                c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                c.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

                updateLabel();
            }
        };
        currentDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), date, c
                        .get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
    private void updateLabel() {

        formattedDate=(df.format(c.getTime()));
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),CalorieMainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("formattedDate", formattedDate);
        intent.putExtra("name", name);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    private void selectdata() {

        System.out.println("inside name"+ name);
        System.out.println("inside selectdata the date recieved "+formattedDate);
        DatabaseHandler helper = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT weight,calorie,fat,carbohydrate,protein FROM login";
        String queryy = "SELECT SUM(totalcalorie) AS dbcalorie,SUM(fat) AS Totalfat,SUM(carbohydrate) AS Totalcarbs,SUM(protein)AS Totalprotein FROM fooditem WHERE created_at = ('"+formattedDate+"')";
        String queryyy = "SELECT SUM(calorieburned) AS dbcalorieburned FROM itemexercise WHERE created_at = ('"+formattedDate+"')";
        System.out.println("THis is the recieving date "+formattedDate);
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        Cursor cursorr = db.rawQuery(queryy,null);
        Cursor cursorrr = db.rawQuery(queryyy,null);

        // there is some record available in the cursor 
        if (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                weight = cursor.getDouble(0);
                calorie = cursor.getDouble(1);
                fat = cursor.getString(2);
                carbohydrate = cursor.getString(3);
                protein = cursor.getString(4);
                Log.e("calorie info","calorie:" + calorie + ", fat:" + fat + ", carbohydrate:" + carbohydrate + ", protein: " + protein );
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        if (!cursorr.isAfterLast()) {
            cursorr.moveToFirst();

            while (!cursorr.isAfterLast()) {
                dbcalorie= cursorr.getDouble(0);
                totalfat = cursorr.getDouble(1);
                totalcarbs = cursorr.getDouble(2);
                totalproteins = cursorr.getDouble(3);
                cursorr.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        if (!cursorrr.isAfterLast()) {
            cursorrr.moveToFirst();

            while (!cursorrr.isAfterLast()) {
                dbcalorieburned= cursorrr.getDouble(0);
                Log.e("calorie info"," dbcalorieburned: " + dbcalorieburned);
                cursorrr.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        cursorr.close();
        cursorrr.close();
        db.close();
    }

}
```

I am attaching series of images for clarification. I am getting 0 value for "cursorrr" for the first.

[image]

Comment: are you talking about calorie burned???

Comment: yes, first time i dont see it. But after changing date or coming back from different pages,then i can see the value.

Answer (score 0):

In your selectdata method, to iterate your sqlite cursor try to use:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
...
}
```

Your values seems to be not correctly initialized the first time you run the selectdata() method.

Comment: finally i got it working. Actually it was not able to load the complete database to sq-lite from MySQL. So i am running this fragment at duration of 5000 milliseconds. To load the complete database.